# Adding smali support for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, antlr, xtext, smali

I am trying to edit a smali project using eclipse. This should in theory allow me to use the whole java magic (opening class definitions, call hierarchies, etc) for smali, too.

Is there already some kind of smali support for eclipse?

As I did not found anything, I am currently thinking about using xtext to build one by my own. (But I am pretty new to xtext.)

I found the smali compiler itself being written using antrl3 the corresponding [grammar description](https://code.google.com/p/smali/source/browse/smali/src/main/antlr3/smaliParser.g) looks like I don't need to specify an xtext grammar from scratch.

Is there a good way to use this description as a base for xtext?

Or is there maybe a better way than xtext in that case?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to directly use an existing grammar with Xtext. The Xtext grammar definition contains more information than an Antlr grammar and this cannot be synthesized by an importer.